# How to pass a plain object to the permissions of CASL (React)

Tags: reactjs, casl

How to pass a condition to the `<Can />` component which is matched with condition in the ability object.

The `AbilityBuilder` which exposes permissions to my app:

```
AbilityBuilder.define((can, cannot) => {
  cannot('delete', 'user', { role: 2 }) // <- 2
});
```

The component which should render a paragraph.

```
<Can I="delete" a="user" of={{ role: 1 }}>
    <p>Should be visible</p> 
</Can>
```

How I can pass an object instead of instance of a class? I have not found any information about that :(

Comment: Just pass it in without using the JSX syntax. If you want to render it in the component use `React.createElement`

Comment: @Andrew Can you show an example?

Comment: I take it back. Just looked at the docs for CASL. I thought this was a generic React question. It kind of looks like you're trying to do something the API isn't built to handle

Comment: As far I know it expects to be something like object. CASL responsibility is to identify an object and compare value of the object to the defined condition? Am I wrong? I think that lib shouldn't care is it instance of a class or object, it should be handled in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common misunderstanding of how to use CASL. Neither `ability.can` nor React's `<Can>` does not support such behavior.

What you need to do instead is to understand what the subject name is and how CASL detects subject name based on passed in `ability.can` object. This is explained in documentation: https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/2017/07/21/check-abilities.html#instance-checks

Also please read https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/59 if information in documentation is not enough.

Also check the example app https://github.com/stalniy/casl-react-example (there is a link to codesanbox, so you can quickly play around with it). Todo app uses similar usecase which you need to implement in your app.

Finally, I created a separate ehancement https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/192, so others will receive an error message with explanation about wrong usage and link to documentation.

Basically you need to define own `subjectName` detection function, and pass user as this:

```js
<Can I="delete" this={{ role: 1, __typename: 'user' }}>
    <p>Should be visible</p> 
</Can>
```

**Update**: `typename` should be a part of object instance in order to prevent collisions (e.g., when objects look the same or similar but have different types). The easiest way to keep consistency between object types and their instances is to use classes. But there other approaches as well, for example GraphQL has `__typename` field which tells client the object type received from server

**Update 2**: by default `Ability` forbids to do everything, so your `AbilityBuilder` can't contain only forbidden rules. You need at least one rule that allows something to do.